# null checking edit textbox android

Tags: android, try-catch

i want to make empty textbox checking for android.  i tried try catch but it was force to close.

below is my codes

```
 try{
                    name    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);    
                    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(KawalanAppXTVT.this).setTitle("Error" )
                        .setMessage("That's not a number")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

can someone help me?

Comment: now it does not force to close but it does not appear alert dialog

Comment: need more code to understand.........

Comment: Always add your LogCat when your app is crashing. It helps more than you realize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check like this :

```
if (name.length() == 0) {
    name.setError("Enter Username");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict input to numbers for your `EditText`, add `android:inputType="number"` to its layout definition xml.

- To check if the field is empty, use `TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText());`
- To check if the contents of the field are numbers `TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(name.getText());`

You don't need the `try...catch` block.

```
// ... onCreate()
name    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name); 

// ... when validating
if(!TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(name.getText())) {
new AlertDialog.Builder(KawalanAppXTVT.this).setTitle("Error" )
                        .setMessage("That's not a number")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

}
```

Comment: No need for `.toString()`, since `isEmpty(...)` works on a `CharSequence` (the mother of all text representations) too. ;)

Comment: I'm guessing its because you have your alert dialog in a catch block. I have updated my answer.